# Getting the first N elements of a vector that do not equal a particular value

Tags: c++, vector

Say I have a std:: vector of size 12. 
I want to pick 6 elements of the vector that don't equal 2 or 30.
How would I do this?

I have tried:

```
for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
         {  if (vector.at(i) != 2 && vector.at(i) != 30)
               {      selected_number = vector.at(i);


               }
             else
               {        selected_number=vector.at(i+1) 


                            }




         }
```

Comment: There are probably about a dozen valid ways to do this depending on what you really have/want.

Comment: `std::copy_if` or `std::remove`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want the first 6 elements of vector `foo` which aren't 2 or 30?

How about

```
std::vector<int> bar;
for(auto i : foo){
  if(i != 2 && i != 30 && bar.size() < 6) {
    bar.emplace_back(i);
  }
}
```

That's not perfect but it's one of the simpler ways to skin this particular cat.

Comment: will bar be filled with any element of foo that is not 2 or 30?

Comment: @ArielBaron try it and see!

Comment: @ArielBaron Without the original typos in my answer it works: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RZj6ZKoixOoFq8Fs

Answer (score 0):

With [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html), you may do

```
auto selectedNumbers = v
                     | ranges::view::filter([](int i) {return i != 2 && i != 30;} )
                     | ranges::view::take(6);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a746b6bb53ade549)

Answer (score 0):

Provide another solution using `std::copy_if`

```
std::vector<int> from_vector;
std::vector<int> to_vector;
// ...
std::copy_if(from_vector.begin(), from_vector.end(),
             back_inserter(to_vector),
             [&to_vector](int i){
                 if(i != 2 && i != 30 && to_vector.size() < 6)
                     return true;
                 else
                     return false;
             });
```